# Run time errors in fortran program with LAPACK on Windows

Tags: gcc, dll, fortran, lapack

I want to run a fortran program (GNU GCC fortran compiler) with  LAPACK library on Windows platform. I followed the instructions outlined in on the webpage http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/ **Build Instructions to create LAPACK and LAPACKE 3.5.0 dlls for Windows with MinGW** I tried using method [Configuring LAPACK in Eclipse-Photran for fortran compiler on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637822/configuring-lapack-in-eclipse-photran-for-fortran-compiler-on-windows).

Compiling a program `test1.f90` with cygwin goes fine, here is command:

```
gfortran test1.f90 -o test1 -L "C:\MinGW\lapack-3.5.0\bin" -llapack
```

- I have lapack installed at "C:\MinGW\lapack-3.5.0", under `lapack-3.5.0\`, libs are in lib folder, dlls are in bin folder
- "C:\MinGW\bin" is added to PATH variable

But I got errors,

- Running with cygwin gives error `error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
- Running with Windows terminal gives error `The program cannot start because liblapack.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem,`

When I checked "C:\MinGW\lapack-3.5.0\bin", liblapack.dll is there. Any idea what is happening here?  Do I need to add the directory of library to the PATH variable? Thanks.

Comment: You might need to use -lm

Comment: `-I` option did not work. Still the same error. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a conjecture, but you might try changing the "C:\" to a Linux directory naming convention, namely from

```
    "C:\MinGW\lapack-3.5.0\bin"
```

to

```
    "/MinGW/lapack-3.5.0/bin"
```

in Settings->C/C++ Build->MinGW C++ Linker-> Libraries -> Library Search Path if you are using Photran.